# rails 4 new action unknown attribute error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the following error

> UnknownAttributeError in PostsController#new
>
> unknown attribute: company_id

posts controller

```
def new
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @post = @company.posts.build
end

def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @post = @company.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private

def post_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :summary, :body)
end
```

routes

```
resources :companies do 
 resources :posts
end
```

models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :posts
end
```

form

```
<%= form_for (@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Post_Title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Post Title" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Post_Summary %>
    <%= f.text_area :summary, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Post Summary" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Post_Post %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "The Post" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit :Submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want each post to belong to a company, a post has attribute `company_id` in its table. I can't figure out why this is not working.

Comment: Please post your view and the post_params method from your posts controller.

Comment: Added view and post_params method

Comment: You know, you still have to pass a company_id in order for your controller to receive it in the params hash. Neither your view nor your params method include company_id. Is this a column that you added in a migration after the table was created?

Comment: `company_id` is passed in the paramaters(in the url). The 'new' view isn't even rendered, do you have a solution?

Comment: Pass `company_id` as `hidden_field` from `form`

Answer (score 0):

Add `company_id` in `post_params`,

**posts_controller.rb**

```
private

def post_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :summary, :body, :company_id)
end
```

Add `company_id` in your form,

```
<%= form_for (@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Post_Title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Post Title" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Post_Summary %>
    <%= f.text_area :summary, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Post Summary" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :Post_Post %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "The Post" %>
  </div>

  <%= hidden_field_tag 'company_id', @company.id %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit :Submit, class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you nest your resources, you're going to end up breaking many of the default paths in your routes.  Usually, this is just a simple fix of updating something like `posts_path` to `company_posts_path(@company)`.

In the case of this form, your `form_for` is sending you to the old `posts#new`, rather than your newly nested one.  I'm going to go ahead and guess that you've still got `resources :posts` in your routes outside of the nested resource you posted.

To fix this, you will want to change the path of your `form_for(@post)` to `form_for([@company, @post])`.  This way, the form will know to send you to the `@post` form that is nested inside of `@company`.